# Enabling systemd service with preseed

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service to output getty to serial console as well as tty0.

I have tried running `systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0` but I suspect that systemd might not be running when late_command is running.

Then I tried making the symlink manually with `ln -s /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/serial-getty@ttyS0.service` and after the install getty.target.wants only contains getty@tty1.service.

I can't use `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8` kernel parameter because then messages from the init system and the system logger will only appear on the first serial port and I want them to appear on tty0.

Does anyone have any experience or any idea on how to enable services in preseed config?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the `late_command` install command line? It's likely that you're running it in the wrong context.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using in-target. `d-i preseed/late_command string in-target ln -s /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/serial-getty@ttyS0.service`

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for [superuser](http://superuser.com) or http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry. Posted on unix exchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306426/enabling-systemd-service-with-preseed